# Obtain column names from MySQL query object (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-6

Currently, I'm storing MySQL query results in an array of objects, where each object represents a row that matches the query. Later, I run through two foreach loops to extract the results - in the example below, they are outputted as a dynamically-generated HTML table.

My question: Is it possible to obtain the **column names** from the query result object? My goal is to be able to dynamically generate the table headings, which my HTML table is currently lacking.

Thanks!

```
$data = array();

$result = db_query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM table");

while ($obj= db_fetch_object($result)) {
    array_push($data, $obj);
}

$ret = "<table>";
foreach ($data as $row) {
   $ret .= "<tr>";
   foreach ($row as $field) {
      $ret .= "<td>$field</td>";
   }
   $ret .= "</tr>";
}
$ret .= "</table>";

return $ret;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like the database has to be queried twice using the above-mentioned method - once to get the rows and once to the column information. Ideally, I'd like to query the database only once.

Comment: not really, how did you came to this?? by this method you can fetch additional info from a query that already ran...

Comment: Yes, you are right - I apologize for misunderstanding the documentation. The column information is extracted from the query result object that is returned. In effect, the database is only queried once to obtain the query result object. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is function to retreive column name. Please check with this link :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but this is how it can be done now with mysqli_*

```
//Function to generate a HTML table from a SQL query
function myTable($obConn,$sql)
{
    $rsResult = mysqli_query($obConn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($obConn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($rsResult)>0)
    {
        //We start with header
        echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\">";
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < mysqli_num_fields($rsResult)){
           $field = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($rsResult, $i);
           $fieldName=$field->name;
           echo "<td><strong>$fieldName</strong></td>";
           $i = $i + 1;
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        //We dump info
        $bolWhite=true;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsResult)) {
            echo $bolWhite ? "<tr bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\">" : "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFF\">";
            $bolWhite=!$bolWhite;
            foreach($row as $data) {
                echo "<td>$data</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```